# (Solved) React/JS How to get the value of last index of props.data which is an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an application that passes array object to a child component and the child component can access the data via "props.data" whose format is as follows:
... Parent component (stateless)

```
const array = [];
for(let i=0; i<totalRows; i++){
    array.push({
        key: i,
        date: new Date(dataObj[i]["properties"]["Date"]).toLocaleString().split(',')[0],
        name: dataObj[i]["properties"]["Name"],
        total_cases: dataObj[i]["properties"]["Total_Cases"],
        cases_today: dataObj[i]["properties"]["Cases_Today"],
        tested_today: dataObj[i]["properties"]["TestedToday"],
        total_deaths: dataObj[i]["properties"]["Deaths"],
        deaths_today: dataObj[i]["properties"]["Deaths_Today"],
    });
}

return(
    <div>
    <div>
        // for each name in array, display line charts
        {array && 
            array.map( name => {
                return <DisplayLineChart 
                            key = {name}
                            data = {array.filter(obj => obj.name === name)}
```

... Child component (stateless)

```
function DisplayLineCharts(props){
      ...
console.log(props.data[props.data.length-1].total_cases); // error
```

... doing "console.log(props.data)" returns

```
246: {key: 3510, date: "10/27/2020", name: "Canada", total_cases: 222887, cases_today: 2674, …}
247: {key: 3522, date: "10/28/2020", name: "Canada", total_cases: 225586, cases_today: 2699, …}
248: {key: 3540, date: "10/29/2020", name: "Canada", total_cases: 228542, cases_today: 2956, …}
249: {key: 3566, date: "10/30/2020", name: "Canada", total_cases: 231999, cases_today: 3457, …}
length: 250
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want to get only the last value of "total_cases" (key) and it shows an error that it's undefined when I tried "props.data[props.data.length-1].total_cases" Any idea what would cause this error?

I can get the last object record when "console.log(props.data[props.data.length-1])" as follows:

```
{key: 3563, date: "10/30/2020", name: "British Columbia", total_cases: 14381, cases_today: 272, …}
cases_today: 272
date: "10/30/2020"
deaths_today: 1
key: 3563
name: "British Columbia"
tested_today: 5488
total_cases: 14381
total_deaths: 263
__proto__: Object
```

Thank you for your time!

Solved this issue by:

```
    var lastDate = "";
// Date: Name, Total_Cases, Cases_Today, TestedToday, Deaths_Today, Percent_Today, Percent_death, Percent_Recovered
for(var i=0; i<totalRows; i++){
    ...

    if (i===totalRows-1){
        lastDate = new Date(dataObj[i]["properties"]["Date"]).toLocaleString().split(',')[0]
    }
}

   return <DisplayLineChart 
                key = {name}
                data = {array.filter(array => array.name === name)}
                name = {name}
                totalCase = {array.filter(array => array.name === name && array.date === lastDate)
                    .map( array => {return array.total_cases;})} 
            />;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get .length of an object, which is not a thing.

you can get .length of an array

using a loop is not a good approach to do this either.

```
const data = Array.from({ length: totalRows }).map((_, i) => ({
        key: i,
        date: new Date(dataObj[i]["properties"]["Date"]).toLocaleString().split(',')[0],
        name: dataObj[i]["properties"]["Name"],
        total_cases: dataObj[i]["properties"]["Total_Cases"],
        cases_today: dataObj[i]["properties"]["Cases_Today"],
        tested_today: dataObj[i]["properties"]["TestedToday"],
        total_deaths: dataObj[i]["properties"]["Deaths"],
        deaths_today: dataObj[i]["properties"]["Deaths_Today"],
}))


console.log('data: ', data)

console.log('lastData: ', data[data.length - 1])
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that obj is initialized as an array and I just pushed objects to the array. I debugged my code and it still doesn't solve my problem. Thank you for a suggestion!